# Questions about optional variable operations in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I set the variable as optional, get the value of the variable from the server, and try to increment it each time the button is pressed.

```
var page: Int? //Received data from previous VC


@IBAction func nextPage(_ sender: Any) {
    (page ?? 0) +=1
}
```

But this code causes an error.

```
Left side of mutating operator isn't mutable: '??' returns immutable value
```

Can I fix this error and increase the value of the optional variable normally?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Initially the `page` variable is nil, thus the left side will fall through `??` operator to 0, so basically you are there trying to execute this code:

```
0 += 1
```

The error message tells you exactly this - the left side of this expression is immutable, because 0 literal is immutable.

You can fix it by this:

```
page = (page ?? 0) + 1
```

Here if `page` is nil, it will execute as:

```
page = 0 + 1
```

If there is a value, then as:

```
page = page + 1
```

Answer (score 4):

While Milan's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57968514/7737192) is definitely correct, I thought it worth mentioning you could also consider changing your page property to be a non-optional variable with a default value of 0. This would somewhat simplify your logic, since you wouldn't need to handle it being an optional (unwrapping, etc).

```
var page: Int = 0 //Received data from previous VC - defaults to 0


@IBAction func nextPage(_ sender: Any) {
    page += 1
}
```

This would obviously only work if you didn't have some other code that is doing something specifically when the page value is nil.